# How i can access original data from the ethernet?

Tags: ethernet

I wanted to access the original value from the ethernet, actully by some hardware programming i am sending a value to system via ethernet ,but it's not possible to access what exactly i'm going to send

Comment: You probably need to be more specific about what you want to do.  What OS is this on?

Comment: And which programming language are you using?

Comment: "Original value from the ethernet" - do you mean physical layer? Link layer? Network layer? Transport layer?  Please be more specific, using OSI model terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a packet sniffer like Wireshark, running on either source or destination system.  This will let you examine packets as they leave or enter, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a protocol analyzer. On Windows, look at [Microsoft's Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en).